# Plutus pioneer program - Lecture #1 - Can't understand behaviour of transactions

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-playground

Why is the second bid of wallet 2 getting ignored when I test it like this? If the first transaction of wallet 2 was also valid, then the second suceeds. I'm just curious if this is somehow expected behaviour or if there is some faulty code on the contract.

Print 1: Tested transactions
[image: Tested transactions]

Print 2: Trace of wallet 2
[image: Trace of wallet 2]

I expected too see any print related to the second bid at least, can't understand why that doesn't happen.

Comment: Isn't the log referring to the first bid  (i.e. Slot 2) made by wallet 2?

Comment: @AronNeewart it is, but that is the whole log for wallet 2. In this scenario there should at least be a " found auction utxo with datum" log too around slot 7. The answer by j.karlsson makes sence though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly there is some problem/bug in the playground, such that when a wallet/transaction fails, no more transactions from that wallet is accepted.
But as you noted when first bid is accepted, the next bid from wallet2 also works.

Comment: That would justify it indeed, thank you!